# req.getConnection is not a function in express-myconnection

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

i am trying to connect mysql, but it is showing me `req.getConnection is not a function`
Bellow is the code snipet which i have used.
**In app.js**

```
var mysql = require('mysql'), 
connection = require('express-myconnection'), 
dbOptions = { 
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root', password: '',
  port: 3306,
  database: 'nodejs'
 }; 
app.use(connection(mysql, dbOptions, 'request'));
```

**In Customers.js**

```
exports.list = function(req, res, next) { 
  req.getConnection(function(err, connection) { 
    if (err) return next(err); 
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM customer', function(err, rows) {
 if (err) console.log("Error Selecting : %s ", err); 
   res.render('customers', { 
     page_title: "Customers - Node.js", data: rows 
   }); 
  }); 
  });
 };
```

Can you please check what is have done wrong. I am pretty new in nodejs, so may be i am missing something.

If you want to check my complete package, please follow bellow URL, i have push all code in my git repository
https://github.com/chiraggmodi/nodeCrud

Comment: app.use requires a function... So you may do app.use((req)=>req.db=connection(mysql,dbOptions,"request")); Then req.db.query("")

Comment: `app.use(function() { connection(mysql, dbOptions, 'request') });` i have tried this way, but same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move this line:

```
app.use(connection(mysql, dbOptions, 'request'));
```

Right now, it's declared *after* your routes, which means that requests will never pass through it (that's how Express works: requests are passed through both middleware and route handlers in order of their declaration).

If you use it to a location in the code before the routes that require `req.getConnection()` to work (perhaps [here](https://github.com/chiraggmodi/nodeCrud/blob/c6246fa58905a683745d442f46f5d232f06d6005/app.js#L35)), requests will *first* pass through the `express-myconnection` middleware and *then* get passed to the route handlers, making sure that `req.getConnection()` will be available inside those route handlers.

**EDIT**: on closer look, your customer routes are also incorrect.

You have this:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('customers', customers.list);
});
```

But `customer.list` is a route handler in itself, not something you should pass to `res.render()`. Instead, try this:

```
router.get('/', customers.list);
```

(and similarly for all the other routes in [`customers_route.js`](https://github.com/chiraggmodi/nodeCrud/blob/master/routes/customers_route.js))

Comment: i have move code above my routes, but still showing same error.