# Why Passport.js code always redirects to failure?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am trying to implement passport.js using localstrategy but unable to redirect to success route. Whenever I click on submit button it always redirect me to failure route. Why this is happening and what should I need to do?

Form code:

```
 <form action="/login" method="post">
    <div>
    <label>Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username"/>
   </div>
    <div>
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Log In"/>
   </div>
  </form>
```

app.js file code:

```
  var express = require('express');
 var app = express();
 var connection = require('express-myconnection');
   var mysql = require('mysql');
  var customers = require('./routes/routes');
  var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  var passport = require('passport')
  var flash = require('connect-flash')
  var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
  var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
  })
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

   app.use(
  connection(mysql, {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
      database: 'nodejs'
    }, 'request')
 );
   app.get('/', customers.form);
  passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, done) {
    console.log('abc');
    customers.checkStatus(username, function (err, user) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown User'});
        }
    });
     }));


 app.post('/login',
   passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/success',
     failureRedirect: '/' }),
   function (req,res) {
   console.log('tets');
     res.redirect('/');
   }
 );


 var server = app.listen(8080, function() {
var host = server.address().address;
var port = server.address().port;
console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port);
 });
```

route.js file code:

```
     exports.form = function(req,res){
    res.render('form', {
        page_title: "Login Form"
      });
  };
exports.success = function (req, res) {
    res.send('wow');
};
exports.checkStatus = function (req, res, username) {
    req.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        connection.query('select * from login where username = ?', 
[username], function(err, rows) {
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: What does customers.form means?What it contains?

Comment: I have created customers as a variable at the top and there I have included route of routes file where form() method is declared

Comment: Split your problem into several chunks and define the source of the problem.

Comment: Ayesha, it is not even going in passport.use function, I am trying console.log but it's not going inside that function.

Comment: Actually I just want to create simple login functionality using passport.js. I am running this code and while pressing submit button it is redirecting me failureRedirect. I think it's not even going inside passport.js function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am able to solve to your problem that not to redirect to failure and after login it is entering into passport function and printing whatever you placed in console.But after entering the details in login form it is redirecting to database connection.There I am getting **TypeError: req.getConnection is not a function** Which I tried to solve it.Even though I am not able to solve this issue.As I don't have much idea about connecting mysql to nodejs.I am working on mongodb.Here I am giving a link with this try to solve this issue [req.getConnection is not a function in express-myconnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520132/req-getconnection-is-not-a-function-in-express-myconnection)

And Replace the app.js code with this I made some changes

```
    var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');
    var ejs = require('ejs');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var session = require('express-session');
    var customers = require('./routes/routes');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var passport = require('passport')
    var flash = require('connect-flash')
    var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
    var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({
      extended: false
      })
    var app = express();
    var mysql = require('mysql'),
        connection = require('express-myconnection');
         app.use(
    connection(mysql, {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
      database: 'nodejs'
    }, 'request')
 );
        app.use(logger('dev'));
        app.use(bodyParser.json());
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
        app.use(cookieParser());
        app.use(session({secret: '{secret}', name: 'session_id', saveUninitialized: true, resave: true}));
        app.use(passport.initialize());
        app.use(passport.session()); 
        app.use(flash()); 
        app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

        passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy(
        function(username, done) {
        console.log('abc');
        customers.checkStatus(username, function (err, user) {
            if (err) throw err;
            else{
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown User'});
            }
            if(user){
                res.send("User");
                }
            }
        });
         }));
       app.get('/login', customers.form);
       app.get('/success',customers.success);
       app.get('/fail',customers.fail)
       app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/success',
         failureRedirect: '/fail',
         failureFlash: true
         }));

    var server = app.listen(8080, function() {

    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("Example app listening at http://localhost:%s", port);
     });
```

And here is routes.js code

```
exports.checkStatus = function (req, res, next) {
    req.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
          if (err) return next(err); 
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM login', function(err, rows) {
       if (err) console.log("Error Selecting : %s ", err); 
   res.render('form', { 
     page_title: "Login form", data: rows 
   }); 
  }); 
  });
 };
exports.form = function(req,res){
      res.render('/give the path of form.ejs', { message: req.flash('loginMessage')
      });
        }
exports.success = function (req, res) {
    res.send('wow');
};
exports.fail= function (req, res) {
    res.send('Noooooo');
};
```

open the browser and try with this `http://localhost:8080/login`.Hope this helps for you...

Comment: Have you resolve the req.connection() issue?If yes.How do you resolve this?

Comment: Ayesha, req.getConnection() was not an issue. Because it is being used to connect mysql database. Though it got connected